# My friend hashes passwords with SHA512 algorithm without salt. How do I convince him that he needs to add salt?

Tags: security, hash, passwords, sha512

Today I discovered something incredibly stupid - my friend hashes user passwords with sha512 algorithm without a salt. I immediately raised this issue to him but he said he wants to see anyone crack a single password in his database. I told him that without a hash his database is vulnerable to rainbow attack but he said no one had this large rainbow table for sha512 as each has is 64 hex characters long.

How do I convince him that he still needs to add salt? Does anyone know what the hash cracking rate of sha512 is? I could argue then that it would take this much or that much time to crack all 8 char passwords, etc.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure

Comment: Try a dictionary attack against his database.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776050/how-long-to-brute-force-a-salted-sha-512-hash-salt-provided

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask you friend if he's got any of the following hashes in his database:

```
b109f3bbbc244eb82441917ed06d618b9008dd09b3befd1b5e07394c706a8bb980b1d7785e5976ec049b46df5f1326af5a2ea6d103fd07c95385ffab0cacbc86
bc547750b92797f955b36112cc9bdd5cddf7d0862151d03a167ada8995aa24a9ad24610b36a68bc02da24141ee51670aea13ed6469099a4453f335cb239db5da
adfb6dd1ab1238afc37acd8ca24c1279f8d46f61907dd842faab35b0cc41c6e8ad84cbdbef4964b8334c22c4985c2387d53bc47e6c3d0940ac962f521a127d9f
3c9909afec25354d551dae21590bb26e38d53f2173b8d3dc3eee4c047e7ab1c1eb8b85103e3be7ba613b31bb5c9c36214dc9f14a42fd7a2fdb84856bca5c44c2
d404559f602eab6fd602ac7680dacbfaadd13630335e951f097af3900e9de176b6db28512f2e000b9d04fba5133e8b1c6e8df59db3a8ab9d60be4b97cc9e81db
3627909a29c31381a071ec27f7c9ca97726182aed29a7ddd2e54353322cfb30abb9e3a6df2ac2c20fe23436311d678564d0c8d305930575f60e2d3d048184d79
ba3253876aed6bc22d4a6ff53d8406c6ad864195ed144ab5c87621b6c233b548baeae6956df346ec8c17f5ea10f35ee3cbc514797ed7ddd3145464e2a0bab413
ddaf35a193617abacc417349ae20413112e6fa4e89a97ea20a9eeee64b55d39a2192992a274fc1a836ba3c23a3feebbd454d4423643ce80e2a9ac94fa54ca49f
c70b5dd9ebfb6f51d09d4132b7170c9d20750a7852f00680f65658f0310e810056e6763c34c9a00b0e940076f54495c169fc2302cceb312039271c43469507dc
0dd3e512642c97ca3f747f9a76e374fbda73f9292823c0313be9d78add7cdd8f72235af0c553dd26797e78e1854edee0ae002f8aba074b066dfce1af114e32f8
401b09eab3c013d4ca54922bb802bec8fd5318192b0a75f201d8b3727429080fb337591abd3e44453b954555b7a0812e1081c39b740293f765eae731f5a65ed1
9719a6439375c9115e01dceda86e210e5f2d78a6cf3f4872997746832c4c0f58c5ae0923fabe5acfb923dfc94a117a7d444e453622912dfa193fc6636581f159
```

In case you're wondering, those are the SHA-512 hashes for `password`, `password1`, `letmein`, `123`, `1234`, `12345`, `123456`, `abc`, `abc123`, `qwerty`, `asdf` and `swordfish` respectively.  You can easily [find more likely candidates](//www.google.com/search?q=most+common+passwords), if you want.

Then have your friend read about [precomputed dictionary attacks](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack) and [rainbow tables](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

Answer (score 3):

Show him, how many values can be calculated with *common hardware*. Nowadays it is about [180 Mega SHA-512 per second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance).

So you can build a rainbowtable...

- containing all words from an English dictionary (≈150'000)
- all names from a telephone book (≈5'000'000)
- and all combinations of characters up to 6 places (20'158'268'676)

...in about **2 minutes**!

Then i would tell him that the length of the resulting hash-value has absolutely nothing to do with the time needed to crack a password.

Even a salted SHA-512 is not enough to make the passwords safe, because this algorithm is ways too fast. That's why one should use a slow algorithm like BCrypt of PBKDF2 with a cost factor.

At last i would just google for some of his hashes, because unsalted rainbowtables already exists in the internet. So the chance is good, that you find one of the weaker passwords.

I collected all this information in a tutorial about [safely storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php). It shouldn't take more than 10 minutes to go through.

Answer (score 0):

Besides rainbowtables, one can also bruteforce a simple hash, see http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/ . Just ask him how long he estimates his users' passwords will resist if you can attack with 2 billion guesses per second.

Modern algorithms, like scrypt, bcrypt, pbkdf2, sha512_crypt (the latter uses sha512, but many rounds) are way slower and thus a brute-force attack would take much much longer.

So what you want is not just to convince him to add a salt to his sha512 hash, but to use a modern "slow" algorithm made for password hashing.